# Spring bean without xml

Tags: spring, mockito, config

Help me please make a spring config jJava file from the xml. In xml bean written as:

```
   <bean id="SettingsControllerDS" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
   </bean>
```

I've tried to write the Java config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"XXXXXXXXXX"})
public class SpringBeanTestApplicationContext {

    @Bean(name = "SettingsControllerDS")
    public DataSource dataSource() { !!! ???????? !!!! }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration class will produce a mocked instance of `DataSource`:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBeanTestApplicationContext {

    @Bean(name = "SettingsControllerDS")
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        return Mockito.mock(DataSource.class); 
    }
}
```